# MySQL error during a large upload of data

Tags: mysql, python

I'm using a python script with the python library `MySQLdb` to upload a large amount of data to a local MySQL database. When I used a sample of the data everything ran fine and uploaded. Now I am using all of my data (it's about 300000 lines split into 12000 text files) and I receive the following error:

```
"OperationalError: (2003, ""Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055)"")"
```

At the point where it crashes it has uploaded 17231 rows of information. I'm using Python 2.7, Win7 64 and MySQL 5.1.53 on a desktop machine. I used a WAMP installation and view the data using PhpMyAdmin. An example of the function I am using to upload the data is as follows:

```
# upload data
def updateDB(db, table, values):

    db = MySQLdb.connect (host = 'localhost', user = 'root', passwd = '', db = db)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    print str(values)
    cursor.execute(makeSQLHeader(table, values), values)     
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

This works fine for the test data, and the text file structure is identical for all of my data. What would be a good strategy to address this problem?

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is timeout issue. How long does your real test take approximately?

Comment: Found this, not sure how valid it is since I haven't worked with python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207981/how-to-enable-mysql-client-auto-re-connect-with-mysqldb

Comment: Not very long, about a fraction of a second.

Comment: Are you opening a connection per file (and are they running in parallel)?

Comment: Yes, I am opening a connection per file. I suppose I can open it before my loop starts and close it at the end?

Comment: although I'm assuming the loop is serial, I think you might be better off only opening one connection for the duration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two thoughts on this are that either it's taking a long time to load and you're disconnecting with a timeout. There are some ways to autoreconnect in python [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207981/how-to-enable-mysql-client-auto-re-connect-with-mysqldb)
Here are the relevant timeout variables in mysql: [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and [interactive_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)

Second idea, and from discussion in comments it looks like the right one. You're probably hitting the [mysql connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) limit by opening a connection per file.

Try opening a single connection and running the test (when you do this, you might hit the timeout, depending on how long it takes).

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you run into the limits of maximum allowed packets. You could set something like this in my.cnf:

```
max_allowed_packet=12M
```

For more information see [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) in the MySQL reference guide.